# What to do with GitHub repository for Android app after switching from Eclipse to Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, github, android-studio

I recently switched to Android Studio from Eclipse for the development of my Android app. Previously, I just had my entire project folder on GitHub, but now that I've switched to Android Studio, everything has changed!

What should I do with my existing GitHub repository? I still have both project folders on my computer. Is there some way to just update the most important files (.java, .xml)? Or should I just make a new repository?

Answer (score 1):

Please, check this article to understand how to migrate eclipse project to android studio project:
https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

You don't need to make changes in your github repo.

Comment: Thanks for the link! That's actually the instructions I followed when I migrated. My question is more along the lines of what to do after I've migrated. More of a philosophical than technical question.

I now have an Eclipse project which is on GitHub and an Android Studio project which isn't. I want to know if there's some way I can keep using my current GitHub repo, or if I should just make a new one.

Comment: You can keep on github code without ide nature (no .project, .iml files) - it's good practice, btw. To run project in your IDEA (Eclipse, Studio, whatever) you will just make local changes to run via selected idea. Smth like this